# .NET Unit Testing on Service that requires it run in it's own context

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am attempting to write unit tests for a windows service which runs as the business layer of a multi-tier application. It doesn't seem feasible to mock the functions of this. Ideally it would be nice to create an instance of the service in the test context. However, when running the service in test context I run into all sorts of issues because the service is running in the unit test context. Things like dlls and classes not being available or xml files missing because it's looking in the test bin directory rather than the service directory.

With all the in memory caching, etc we do, we need the service running in order to really test it. Is there a way to run the service in it's own context, rather than the test context and still unit test it? I feel like I'm at a loss here.

Comment: What you describe are not unit tests. Look into integration testing. The code seems too tightly coupled to be flexible enough for unit tests.

Comment: I agree with Nkosi. If the code was more loosely-coupled then it would be easier to maintain, and easier to write *genuine* unit tests, where mocking could be used to overcome the problems you describe of trying to test it as it stands.

Comment: We're talking about an enormous system that will not be re-written to decouple. The goal is to test the available methods and validate the functionality. The problem is running the service object in the test context. If there's no way around this, that's fine, but I'm trying to determine if it's possible.

Comment: Some of the issues you are describing will go away if you turn off Shadow Copy. But not most of them. The effort required to integration test this outweighs the effort to Refactor it, and Unit Test it in smaller chunks.